# UIImageView delay when adding to another UIView

Tags: performance, ios5, uiview, uiimageview

This is my first post here - but I've been a reader for a long time. Thank you so much for this site! :-)

I am currently working on a port of my XNA-based 2D engine from WP7 to iOS (5). I would prefer not to use OpenGL directly, because I prefer to invest my time more in gameplay than in technique. So I would be very happy to get an answer not involving OpenGL (directly).

The problem:
When I add an UIImageView to another UIView, there is a short delay before the UIImageView gets drawn. I assume, this is due to the caching the UIView-class performs before converting everything internally to OpenGL then drawing.

What I want:
Tell the UIView (superview) to perform all neccessary calculations for all subviews and *then* draw them *all* at once.
Currently the behaviour I observe ist: Calculate uiimageview_1, draw uiimageview_1, calculate uiimageview_n, draw uiimageview_n, ...

Dummycode of what I want:

```
// put code here to tell superview to pause drawing
for (int i = 0; i < 400; i ++)
{
    add UIImageView[i] to superview;
}
// put code here to tell superview to draw now
```

Possible workaround (but coming from C# & Windows, I have no idea how to implement it efficiently in Objective-C on iOS) - I am afraid that this code is inefficient because large blocks of RAM had to be transferred (per frame!) on retina displays at native resolution:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 400; i ++)
{
    add UIImageView[i] to superview;
}
// put code here to get a bitmap in ram from superview
// return bitmap and draw it in a view for the scenery/canvas
```

Any help on how to approach this "popping"-problem would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please try to use proper spelling (especially casing) in your posts. That makes them more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering this will be a bit tricky. The exact behavior of Cocoa Touch is undocumented (an 'implementation detail' says Apple), so recommendations can only be given based on guessing and experience.

Instead of working with UIViews, you might want to try CoreAnimation. It abstracts 2D drawing and compositing operations without the overhead of a UI framework such as UIKit. It also much easier to use than programming OpenGL directly. UIKit uses CoreAnimation to do it's drawing, but augments it in many ways. This 'augmentation' might be exactly the reason why you're hitting performance problems.

Have a look at the [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coreanimation_guide/introduction/introduction.html) and judge for yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I'll first have a closer look at that and if it doesn't improve performance at least 30%, I'll check out Cocos2D.

Comment: this actually improved performance by about 50%. don't forget to include QuartCore.framework in your project and to import <QuartzCore/QuarzCore.h> in your implementation files.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - forget about UIKit's views. If you trying to port XNA game to iOS, I'd recommend to familiarize yourself with Cocos2D. It's more convenient than core OpenGL, and it'll give you performance you need.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a closer look at that as soon as I tried out CoreAnimation (if this doesn't solve my issues). Currently I am rendering 100 animated sprites at ~30fps on a iPod Touch 4, which is "OK" but not good.

Comment: There's no way you can go around using Cocos2D or OpenGL for that matter - Cocos2D is built on OpenGL without having you really code OpenGL. It will provide you with performance tenfold from what CoreAnimation has to offer.

Comment: sounds performance-wise very promising. can you also mix user interface-elements like UIButton or UILabel with your game-visuals? This is the major problem with XNA (it's not possible there, you have to build your own UI which is insanely time-consuming) and the major reason why I would very much like to use the UIView (or CoreAnimation)-approach *IF* I get enough performance. But I certainly keep your words in mind in case the CoreAnimation-approach doesn't boost 40%. Thank you very much for your time.